# Recording pcm file and playing it through Audiotrack crashing

Tags: java, android, eclipse

i am recording a pcm file thorugh AudioRecorder and create a file in sdcard. when recording is done i play the same file with Audiotrack but it crash. in logcat it says "Invalid audio buffer size". also my file size on sdcard is 0.0kb ,which i didn't understand why. here is the code. `

```
public void startRecord() {

        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                "test.pcm");

        int sampleFreq = 11025;

        try {
            file.createNewFile();

            OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
            BufferedOutputStream bufferedOutputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(
                    outputStream);
            DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(
                    bufferedOutputStream);

            int minBufferSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(sampleFreq,
                    AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO,
                    AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);

            short[] audioData = new short[minBufferSize];

            AudioRecord audioRecord = new AudioRecord(
                    MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC, sampleFreq,
                    AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO,
                    AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, minBufferSize);

            audioRecord.startRecording();

            while (recording) {
                int numberOfShort = audioRecord.read(audioData, 0,
                        minBufferSize);
                for (int i = 0; i < numberOfShort; i++) {
                    dataOutputStream.writeShort(audioData[i]);
                }
            }

            audioRecord.stop();
            dataOutputStream.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void PLaying(int explosion) {

        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                "test.pcm");

        int shortSizeInBytes = Short.SIZE / Byte.SIZE;

        int bufferSizeInBytes = (int) (file.length() / shortSizeInBytes);
        short[] audioData = new short[bufferSizeInBytes];

        try {
            InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
            BufferedInputStream bufferedInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(
                    inputStream);
            DataInputStream dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(
                    bufferedInputStream);

            int i = 0;
            while (dataInputStream.available() > 0) {
                audioData[i] = dataInputStream.readShort();
                i++;
            }

            dataInputStream.close();

            int sampleFreq = explosion;

            AudioTrack audioTrack = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
                    sampleFreq, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO,
                    AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, bufferSizeInBytes,
                    AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);

            audioTrack.play();
            audioTrack.write(audioData, 0, bufferSizeInBytes);

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do You have integrated the stop method? Please Show us a Little bit more code. The Problem is, if You haven´t implemented a correct stop mehtod, it will Loop forever..Have You done something like this:

```
   yourStopButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

         @Override
         public void onClick(View view){

             recording=false;
      }

   });
```

And then, don´t Forget to do the same in onStart and set recording to true.

Comment: yes i have added stop code exactly the way you have done in above answer. the problem was actually with my device . i changed the device and it worked . thanks for the help.

Comment: yes exactly i have done the same. now working. it was my device which was troubling.

Comment: ok, so You should handle this issue if You think about to publish such a Kind of app. Maybe some other devices got this Problem too

Answer (score 0):

This code looks dodgy

```
while (recording) {
      int numberOfShort = audioRecord.read(audioData, 0,
                    minBufferSize);
      for (int i = 0; i < numberOfShort; i++) {
                dataOutputStream.writeShort(audioData[i]);
      }
}
```

What is the value of `recording`.  Where does the value change.   If it does not change it will be an endless loop (unless and exception is thrown).

Comment: yes your are right , but i have managed that part pretty well.it was actually my device which was troubling me. i changed the device and it worked but that took an hour to figure out  exact error.

Answer (score 0):

Divide the  minimum buffer size by 2 when constructing the AudioRecord instance